# how to get the value passed by $.post ajax in php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

My Ajax call is something like,

```
    var txt=$('#keyword').value;
    $.post("ajax.php?for=result", {suggest: "keyword="+txt}, function(result){
   $("#search_result").html(result);
     });
```

In my php file, i want to get the value of textbox with id 'keyword', which is passed like

```
var txt=$('#keyword').value;
$.post("ajax.php?for=result", {suggest: "keyword="+txt},
```

I tried in my php file using
$_POST and $_GET method, but it gives me an error like 'Undefined Index'

How can we get that value in php file?.
Also provide me an example of how to do this using json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not post the values properly.

The proper way of posting values is either as a plain object

```
var txt=$('#keyword').value;
$.post("ajax.php?for=result", {keyword: txt}, function(result){
   $("#search_result").html(result);
});
```

**OR** as a string of key=value seperated with '&'

```
var txt=$('#keyword').value;
$.post("ajax.php?for=result", "keyword="+txt, function(result){
   $("#search_result").html(result);
});
```

Comment: It works , thank u.. Can you please provide me an example of doing this using json?

Comment: but, only the second code works for me.. first code gives the same error

Comment: Use `$.post(url, data, function(result){}, "json");` to define the DataType. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

js:

```
 var txt=$('#keyword').value;
    $.post("ajax.php?for=result", {suggest:txt}, function(result){
   $("#search_result").html(result);
     });
```

ajax.php :

```
$keyword = $_POST['suggest'];
```